# Detach Event on YUI 3

Tags: javascript, touch, yui3

I try to detach a 'touchstart' element, on a "back" button, with YUI 3.

But nothing is detach. When I touch on the "back" button, both of functions are called.

Here my code :

```
Y.all('.back').detachAll('touchstart');
Y.all('.back').on('touchstart',function(e){
     alert('types'); 
     loadMainframe(myURL);
     e.preventDefault();
});

Y.all('.back').detachAll('touchstart');
Y.all('.back').on('touchstart',function(e){ 
     alert('resto'); 
     loadMainframe(myURL);
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found.

You can detach events, only for the Y element that you are using.

I used a global element

```
YEvent = YUI().use('node','touch-event');
```

and now i make my detach() and on() on the YEvent element, and it's working.